# Gilead replacement to glue GWT and Hibernate together

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, gilead

Till recently Gilead looked like the best solution to glue GWT and Hibernate together.
Unfortunately, Gilead project seems to be abandoned and was not upgraded for new GWT 2.5, which makes us look for a replacement.

Do you know of any new project that essentially does the same thing Gilead was doing for older versions of GWT?

Answer (score 3):

It's a slightly different programming model (using proxy objects instead of real the actual data model objects), but I would recommend using the official GWT requestfactory as a replacement: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory

We've found it to be a much better programming model as it doesn't force you to keep your model classes clear of any server side code. I believe it also has a number of performance benefits as it automatically manages changes as delta's rather than reserialising the entire object.

Comment: Thank you for point out to the request factory. I'll have to take a closer look, but after the first glance it seems like I'll have to create another layer of classes for that to work. I'm not a fan of polluting functional code with multiple layers of POJOs that have no value added to the actual functionality and potentially are prone to typos, etc. But I'll have to study myself first, of course.

Answer (score 1):

In my dev team we're using [dehibernator](https://code.google.com/p/dehibernator/) to get rid of Hibernate proxies and lazy collections before sending the entities to the client. It's simple and effective.

Answer (score 1):

This seems worth a try: [Gilead fork for GWT 2.7.0](https://github.com/emsouza/gilead)

Comment: finally got to try it out and can confirm it works :)